# GAS calendar name and Gmail used name differ for default calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

`getCalendarsByName` was failing due to a wrong calendar name.

I realised that, for my default calendar, the GAS name is not the same as the one showed by Gmail Calendar app,  also defined in the "Calendar Name" field of the calendar settings, but the used name is the Gmail address.

Is this behaviour by design?   I did not find any mention to it.

## EDIT

As requested, here's a test function to reproduce the problem:

```
function testCalendars(){

  var test = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Test calendar')[0];  
  var def = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var mail = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('mymail@gmail.com')[0];  
  var all = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var defdisp = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Def cal displayed name')[0];  

  Logger.log('test: ' + test.getName());
  Logger.log('def: ' + def.getName());
  Logger.log('mail: ' + mail.getName());
  Logger.log('all[0]: ' + all[0].getName());
  //Logger.log('defdisp: ' + defdisp.getName());


}
```

`'Test calendar'` is a calendar created using: 'Create new calendar'. The name is the one displayed on the left list of the Calendar app and in `Calendar settings->Calendar Name`.

`'mymail@gmail.com'` is the address associated with the account.

`'Def cal displayed name'` is the upper calendar name displayed  on calendar list in the the Calendar app and the related value of `Calendar settings->Calendar Name`.

The log gives:

```
[14-03-16 17:25:00:620 CET] test: Test calendar
[14-03-16 17:25:00:620 CET] def: mymail@gmail.com
[14-03-16 17:25:00:621 CET] mail: mymail@gmail.com
[14-03-16 17:25:00:621 CET] all[0]: mymail@gmail.com
```

Uncommenting:

```
  //Logger.log('defdisp: ' + defdisp.getName());
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show an example that does not work ?

Using this code I get perfectly coherent results.

```
function test(){
  var def = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var defName = def.getName()
  Logger.log('default Calendar is "'+defName+'"');
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(defName);
  Logger.log('result cal is "'+cal[0].getName()+'"');
}
```

This returns the following log :

[image]

Then I changed de calendar name like this :

[image]

and get the following log :

[image]

I can only confirm that everything is normal.

---

EDIT : please test also all your calendars using a small script like this:

```
function testCalendars(){
  var all = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();  
  for(var n in all){
    Logger.log('all['+n+']: ' + all[n].getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure I understand what this means : *"'Def cal displayed name' is the upper calendar name displayed on calendar list in the the Calendar app and the related value of Calendar settings->Calendar Name."*

Comment: follow: [https://www.google.com/calendar/render?tab=mc](https://www.google.com/calendar/render?tab=mc). On the left there is the list of the calendars. The first name from the top should be the default calendar. Click on its context menu and then click 'Calendar settings'. Among the settable values you find 'Calendar Name', the name here is like that on which you clicked before.

Comment: "please test also all ...". This is what I did and so I discovered that the displayed name is not present and `CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()[0]` uses the email instead.

Comment: ok, I get it... my test gives expected results, if I change the name of my default calendar I can get it by its new name absolutely without issue as shown in my answer.edit : and getAllCalendars returns cal objects with the right names... I don't know why it doesn't work for you but it does for me.